# locking during nservicebus handler

Tags: locking, message-queue, nservicebus

I have a scenario wherein a nservicebus message handler I need to prevent multiple messages for the same saga from being executed at the same time.

The handler for arguments sake does something like this  (way oversimplified in this example(

Message:

```
public class MyMessage : IMessage {
  public int OrderId {get;set;}
  public int NewQuantityLevel {get;set;}
}
```

Saga:

```
public void Handle(MyMessage message)
{
    // call remote service to get current order quantity
    // do some logic and update remote service with difference between original and new quantity

    Bus.Send(new MyOtherMessage())
}
```

Now I'm my process I can receive 2 or more of these messages at any time and I do not want to have them retrieve an order quantity that may already be in the process of being updated or modified somewhere else.

I have considered a few solutions:

1. Obtain a mutex for the order (currently we only have one instance of the worker running on a single machine, but there is potential in the future to have multiple, in which case we might use a redis lock or something similar)
2. Use sql locking in the service to take a serialized lock on the rows/data (not sure if this would even work however)

Neither of these really seem optimal and it does feel like I'm working against the framework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The saga is the lock.**

As @Hadi mentions, NServiceBus will use optimistic concurrency to make sure that only a single message gets to update a saga instance at a time.

Instead of doing the update directly in the saga, store the fact that you are doing the update and send a message to do the remote service invocation to a separate message handler in a different endpoint. Storing the fact on the saga and sending the message to perform it will either BOTH be done or not at all. If two messages try to do this at the same time, only one will complete successfully. The other message will get a concurrency exception, roll back to the queue and eventually be retried.

At that time it will see that there is already a quantity update operation happening. You can then either discard the second message or store some state on the saga to make sure the second quantity update happens once the first completes.

Moving the remote service invocation outside the saga together with full-duplex request/response messaging ensures a good separation of concerns between the saga, as the process manager, and the message handler, as the integration point.

***Pseudo code***

```
public class MySaga
{
    public void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {
        if(Data.CurrentlyUpdatingQuantity)
            return; //or schedule for later

        Data.CurrentlyUpdatingQuantity = true;

        Bus.Send(new PerformQuantityUpdateMessage(message.OrderId));    
    }

    public void Handle(QuantityUpdateResponse message)
    {
        Data.CurrentlyUpdatingQuantity = false;
        Bus.Send(new MyOtherMessage());
    }
}
```

Separate messagehandler (NOT PART OF THE SAGA)

```
public void Handle(PerformQuantityUpdateMessage message)
{
    // call remote service to get current order quantity
    // do some logic and update remote service with difference between original and new quantity

    Bus.Reply(new QuantityUpdateResponse(message.OrderId));    
}
```

Comment: Should I use the delayed delivery to reschedule the message or track it myself and check within the hander?

Comment: For this case, I would probably track it by storing "I need to do another Update Quantity" operation in the saga data. Then check that flag first thing in `Handle(QuantityUpdateResponse)` and send another `PerformQuantityUpdateMessage` if needed. This way you can batch up multiple extra `MyMessage` into a single quantity update operation and be certain that it will be performed as soon as the initial one finishes.

Comment: Wouldn't the messages that occur in the mean time not be able to update the saga data, assuming they are for the same unique key

Comment: That should work fine. As long as the orderId is the same, it will always map to the same saga instance. (At least until you explicitly finish the saga)

Answer (score 4):

You probably shouldn't be doing this in your saga:

> // call remote service to get current order quantity

Instead, that should be moved out to a separate endpoint to which the saga, as the process manager, interacts with in a full-duplex request/response messaging manner.

So, when the saga gets that first trigger message which starts it, it sends a request message to the RemoteServiceInvocationEndpoint, and updates its state to indicate that it is waiting for a response.

The RemoteServiceInvocationEndpoint after getting a response from the remote service will send a response message back to the saga.

When the saga gets that response message, it will know that the process is done and then perform any final actions that are needed - like sending out other messages.

If the saga gets another trigger message, it can check its state and see that it has already sent a request message out and know not to send another one.

As @Hadi said in his response, the concurrency-control mechanisms in NServiceBus will guarantee that a saga will only successfully process one message at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to create a secondary saga as the update on itself is a long running process? When the update saga has finished its work, it can signal the original saga to continue.

As for how NServiceBus handles concurrent sagas there are two cases:

- When multiple saga start message come in, only one will commit. The other messages will fail and get picked up by retries. On the second attempt the saga already exists and a second instance is not created. This will ensure only one saga is created.
- When you access the saga concurrently (e.g. to update the state) the persistance storage concurrency settings take effect. If using RavenDB, NServiceBus turns on the [optimistic concurrency support](https://ravendb.net/docs/search/3.5/csharp?searchTerm=how-to%20enable-optimistic-concurrency).

This is all documented in greater detail in [this page](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/concurrency) on NServiceBus documentation.

Should you need to ensure only one instance of the saga exist per batch (e.g. if you can correlate the saga with say ProductId that you want to lock on), you can use that as the correlation Id so only one saga exists per *batch*.

If you want solely one saga instance (more like a singleton saga) you can use a no-op correlation logic, along with a custom saga finder. This way you can still scale the endpoint and other handlers / sagas won't suffer. This technique is shown [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/04/17/saga-implementation-patterns-singleton/).